# Using the ADO.NET DB2 connector - can I determine which DB2 system I'm connected to?

Tags: db2

The iSeries DB2 is very different from the Windows/Linux DB2. We need to know which because we have selects to retrieve the metadata (table names, etc.) and those selects are dependent on what DB2 we're talking to.

Is there a way, after we have a connection, to determine what DB2 product we're hitting?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property on the ADO.NET connection object ([DB2Connection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClass.html)), [ServerType](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClassServerTypeProperty.html), that returns a different value based on which product you're connected to.

I haven't been able to find an exhaustive list of what the values correspond to, but the ones I've personally run into are the following:

`DB2` - z/OS DB2

`DB2/LINUXX8664` - DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows running on 64-Bit Linux

`DB2/NT` - DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows running on Windows (32 bit?)

`DB2/NT64` - DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows running on Windows (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

May by whith db2 connect or db2 lelvel

check [this](http://onewebsql.com/blog/finding-your-db2-version)

Comment: I don't think those will work - they're command line calls. I need some way using the ADO.NET connector. thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

```
select catalog_name from qsys2/catalog_name
```

It's a one liner that returns a name.